# Renaming job in jenkins/hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have tried to rename a hudson/jenkins job. However it failed to rename.

Is there any way so I can rename the job?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can rename selected job through jenkins UI by following these steps:

```
job>configure>Advanced Project Options>Display Name
```

Other way is to rename the directory on the `Jenkins/hudson` server and then `restart` the `Jenkins`.

Comment: You don't have to restart Jenkins to pick up a renamed job directory. You can Manage `Jenkins>Reload Configuration from Disk` or just hit http://your-jenkins-server/reload. Note that the if you change a job name you will need to manually change any other job that tries to call the renamed job.

Comment: I suspect that the solution given by @marc.guenther is more correct, as this appears to refer to the name that is displayed, and not the actual job name.

Comment: Be aware that the manual renaming of the job folder on file system level (same as moving jobs into a different folder via UI) will not update data folders of plugins using the job name as well, e.g. config history plugin

Comment: This doesn't really rename the job though. It just changes what is displayed.

Answer (score 24):

For Quick understanding I used some screenshots:

I used Jenkins version: 2.148

**Step 1:**

On home screen / Job list just click on job option.

[image]

OR

Just open Job details you will see left side option for rename.

[image]

**Step 2:**

Enter new name and just click on **Rename button**

[image]

Comment: Nice and easy - no need to overcomplicate.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to rename a project but just changing the name to capitals?

Comment: @KR29 I think no direct way, but you can rename test >> test1 then back to rename to Test. something you can do it. I have tried and its working.

Answer (score 18):

Just for the sake of completeness, want to mention the update of Hudson job name using Groovy [script console](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Hudson+Script+Console):

```
// Groovy script to rename job in Hudson
import hudson.model.*;

def JOB_PATTERN = ~/^MY_JOB.*$/; //find all jobs starting with "MY_JOB".
def NEW_PART = "_NEW"

(Hudson.instance.items.findAll { job -> job.name =~ JOB_PATTERN }).each { job_to_update -> 
    println ("Updating job " + job_to_update.name);
    def new_job_name = job_to_update.name + NEW_PART; //Append new part to the job name
    println ("New name: " + new_job_name);
    job_to_update.renameTo(new_job_name);
    println ("Updated name: " + job_to_update.name);
    println("="*80);
}
```

Rather helpful if you need to update several dozens of jobs at the same time.

**Note**: The following code will not work:

```
job_to_update.name = new_job_name;
job_to_update.save();
```

Setting the name of the job to new and saving configuration will not rename current job, but create a copy of the job configuration with a new name. Also, in this case, there might be broken references, so Hudson will need to have configuration reloaded.

Comment: Does this rename the whole job or just replace MY_JOB with whatever new part you choose?

Comment: In the given example I am just updating the job name with adding "_NEW" suffix to all the jobs that start with search string "MY_JOB". The method 'renameTo()' will set the job name to the string you provide as parameter. If you want to replace part of the job do that before calling renameTo() and then pass the new name string to the method.

Comment: This being such an old example, only finds jobs listed at the top level, not inside folders. Note also that it really renames the job, so the URL changes. _Not just cosmetic._

Answer (score 11):

The normal way to rename a job:

Go to the **Configure** screen and edit the **Project name** field right on top. Then click on **Save** and confirm by clicking on **Yes**. *(do **not** click on the **Apply** button next to **Save**, that will give you an error message: [JENKINS-17474](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17474))*

Changing the **Display Name** will not rename the job, it only changes how it will be displayed. It will still be found under it's original name via the search box for example and that also will show up in the url.

Renaming directories on the filesystem level should really not be necessary.

Comment: Note that the field label appears to vary based on the type of project, as mine says "Maven project name" and not "Project name".

Comment: "Renaming on filesystem level should not be necessary" -- well, if you have spaces in the directory name, that causes script issues.

Comment: Meanwhile (v2.179) the UI doesn't allow changing the project name anymore but there is the rename option as mentioned by Rikin Patel

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a new job with new name, there will be an option of `copy from` an existing job.
2. `copy from` the job you want to rename.
3. Delete the original job.

Now you have an identical job with a different name.

Answer (score 2):

I can't make Marc's script work, so write one based on Disable all jobs script as shown below. This is to rename any project with "Findur.OpenComponent" to "Findur.OpenComponents".

```
import hudson.model.*

renameChildren(Hudson.instance.items)

def renameChildren(items) {
  for (item in items) {
    if (item.class.canonicalName != 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder') {     
      if (( m = item.name =~ /^(Findur.OpenComponent)(\..*)$/)){
        println(item.name)
        println m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2)
        newname = m[0][1] + 's' + m.group(2)
        item.renameTo(newname)
      }

    } else {
        renameChildren(((com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder) item).getItems())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please attribute source: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bulk+rename+projects

Comment: @Jayan clearly they are the author of that snippet too from the author field.

Comment: NOTE: The `item.renameTo(newname)` line really does rename the job, i.e. the URL changes. _Not just cosmetic._ If you only want to set the `item.displayName` then do that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the requirement I usually choose between:

*Job* > *Configure*
- modify *Project Name* property 
- **Advanced Project Options**, hit *Advanced...*, set value for *Display Name*

Then *Save* the job. No need to rename on file system level.

Comment: Job is the selected jenkins job you want to rename, if you have admin permissions there is a *configure* link in the sidebar.

Comment: Yes I have admin permissions...and I can see `configure` link to the right sidebar, but inside the configuration wizard where is the `modify Project Name property - Advanced Project Options`

Comment: I am using Jenkins ver. 1.499

Comment: The *Project Name* is the first field in the configuration screen. It is editable, when you click save you'll be asked if you want to change the project name. Click yes. For the second option... Scroll a little until you see the section **Advanced Project Options** - on the right side there is an *Advanced...* button that you need to click, then you see and can modify the display name.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [`Job.previousNames()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/b354ca01bf75efbe8cd8a3b58738dc3b323fbb27/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/Job.groovy#L65) to rename multiple jobs using Groovy script within a [job generator](Job Generator Plugin) (factory).

The following example renames the jobs `ci.*_2` to `ci.*` (it removes the trailing `_2`).

```
[
    [env: '01', hostname: 'host01.intranet'],
    [env: '02', hostname: 'host02.intranet'],
    [env: '03', hostname: 'host03.intranet'],
    [env: '04', hostname: 'host04.intranet'],
    [env: '05', hostname: 'host05.intranet'],
    [env: '06', hostname: 'host06.intranet'],
    [env: '07', hostname: 'host07.intranet'],
    [env: '08', hostname: 'host08.intranet'],
    [env: '09', hostname: 'host09.intranet'],
    [env: '10', hostname: 'host10.intranet'],
    [env: '11', hostname: 'host11.intranet'],
    [env: '12', hostname: 'host12.intranet'],
    [env: '13', hostname: 'host13.intranet'],
    [env: '14', hostname: 'host14.intranet'],
    [env: '15', hostname: 'host15.intranet'],
    [env: '16', hostname: 'host16.intranet'],
    [env: '17', hostname: 'host17.intranet'],
    [env: '18', hostname: 'host18.intranet'],
    [env: '19', hostname: 'host19.intranet'],
    [env: '20', hostname: 'host20.intranet'],
].each { Map config ->
    job("ci.${config.env}") {
        previousNames("ci.${config.env}_2")
        description("Continuous Integration on host ${config.env}")
        logRotator {
            numToKeep(5)
            daysToKeep(45)
        }
        label('build')
        wrappers {
            colorizeOutput('gnome-terminal')
        }
    }
}
```